# MongoDB - find documents with couple conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation

Requirement:
COUNT all documents in the collection WHERE
objects.objectType equal to 'group'
AND
(objects.objectType NOT equal to 'person' && relation equal to 'Exposed_to')

Expected: will return count of all documents WHERE objects.objectType equal to 'group' AND which does not contain any (objectType:person && realtion:Exposed_to) under 'objects' array.

An example of matched document:

```
"objects": [
    {
    "objectType": "organization",
    "relation": "Exposed_to"
    },
    {
    "objectType": "group",
    "relation": "Exposed_to"
    }
]
```

An example of document that shouldn't be counted:

```
"objects": [
    {
    "objectType": "person",
    "relation": "Exposed_to"
    },
    {
    "objectType": "group",
    "relation": "Exposed_to"
    }
]
```

i have tried the following query:

```
.count({
'objects.objectType': 'group',
'objects': {
    $elemMatch: {
    $and: [{'objectType' : {$ne: 'person'}, 'relation': 'Exposed_to'}]
    }
}})
```

but it seems to be not working correctly.
i am not sure if i should use aggregation in this case- i also have less knowledge in this area.

i will be glad to get some help. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it working for you? https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q-dj7_O_AJR
This playground doesn't support `count`, so I replace by `find`

```js
db.collection.find({
  $and: [
    {
      "objects.objectType": "group"
    },
    {
      objects: {
        $not: {
          "$elemMatch": {
            "objectType": "person",
            "relation": "Exposed_to"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, it works!
i see now what i have missed there. that was very helpful.